# Proper display for Rejection of Request

Tags: status, process, displays, flow

I'm currently working on a project where user submit a media request, which then will be reviewed by another user (verifier).

I have done the display of information, but I'm not sure how can I show the "Rejection Reason". For me this seems to be important, so I was thinking on putting it on top of the page, but this "Rejection Reason" use WYSIWYG editor meaning photos/attachment, or any text formatting is possible.

Also I was thinking... does it make sense to show the request details anymore, or do I just need to show the "Rejection Reason"?

Please note that once the request is rejected, we won't allow it to be editing. So user have to create a request again. (So far that our process, if that's wrong, let me know)

[image]
*This is the original wire frame of the idea, think of it as youtube like*

Comment: Can you send visualisation of interface?

Comment: @PiotrŻak, I have updated the my question! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so:

I think it can be simply  implemented in status: **Accepted / Processing / Rejected.**
and under status the cause of rejection (stochastically, you need to consider all ranges of errors to implement).

In addition, statuses can be distinguished by color:

- **Accepted** - green
- **Rejected** - red
- **Processing** - orange
- **New** - blue

I guess there is also a list with  individual ideas / objects you should consider displaying the status there as well.

It's important to provide feedback to the user.

**For example:**

User trying add photo - it can't be accepted because the size is > 5MB.

if he doesn't get info he will not be able to perform this operation again 
because he will not know the reason for rejection.

When the error is displayed - it is able to react and optimize the size.

Comment: ah yes, the form validation will be placed to let the user know. However, on this sample the Rejection will be considered as a process where another person would "verify" the media then it will be returned to the uploader with the details or reason for rejection

Comment: In that case, display the CTA elements (Accept/Reject) and text-input, visible only to the current role in the system.


The verification process can be automated, unless the terms of acceptance depend on the policy / ethics / regulations.

Comment: In the future, you can consider a panel of this role with all processing elements displayed